# How can I relate the conductivity (uS/cm) at various temperatures of an aqueous solution of NaCl with ionic strength?

Tags: electrochemistry

Can someone give the relationship between conductivity (uS/cm) with ionic strength please ? In some sources they that there is a linear relationship with a constant, but with no explanation to come up with it.